# change audio src in an array when click on each a tag (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change audio src when I click on each a tags, for example when I click on the first a tag, just the first src in the array should play and so on.
I wrote this code but by clicking on a tags the src will change every time (I want the first src just for the first a tag and second for second...);

```
  $(function () {
        const sources = [
            '1',
            '2',
            '3',
            '4',
            '5',
            '6',
            '7',
            '8',
            '9',
            '10'
        ];

        for (var i = 0; i < $('a').length; i++) {
            $('a').eq(i).on('click', function () {
                if (i <
                    sources.length ) {
                    i++;
                } else {
                    i = 0;
                }
                $('#music').attr('src', sources[i]);
                $('#music').get(0).play();
            })

        };

    });
```

Comment: Why do you modify `i` in the header of the loop and the loop itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you right then you can use [`$.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) to get the source to the clicked `<a>` element.

> `.index()` / `.index( selector )` / `.index( object )`
>
> **Description**: Search for a given element from among the matched elements.
>
> **Return Values**
> If no argument is passed to the `.index()` method, the return value is
> an integer indicating the position of the first element within the
> jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.
>
> If `.index()` is called on a collection of elements and a DOM element or
> jQuery object is passed in, `.index()` returns an integer indicating the
> position of the passed element relative to the original collection.
>
> If a selector string is passed as an argument, `.index()` returns an
> integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery
> object relative to the elements matched by the selector. If the
> element is not found, `.index()` will return -1.

```js
$(function() {
  const sources = [ '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10' ],
        anchors = $("a");

  anchors.on('click', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  
    const indexOfClickedAnchor = anchors.index(this),
          source = sources[indexOfClickedAnchor];
  
    console.log(indexOfClickedAnchor, source);
  
    /* 
    $('#music').attr('src', source)
               .get(0)
               .play();
    */
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="">1</a><a href="">2</a><a href="">3</a><a href="">4</a><a href="">5</a>
<a href="">6</a><a href="">7</a><a href="">8</a><a href="">9</a><a href="">10</a>
```

Comment: _"just the first audio(src) pauses not the others"_ - There's only one `#music` element o.O

Answer (score 0):

the `i` variable is hoisted so you should declare it as let (if ES2015 is possible) or use a closure for that. Also, you probably shouldn't modify `i` inside the loop as you did so that you wouldn't need to account for an infinite loop case. A better loop would be:

```
const a = $('a');
for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].on('click', function () {
        $('#music').attr('src', sources[i % sources.length]);
        $('#music').get(0).play();
    })
};
```

Comment: You might want to store the result of `$('a').length` in a variable. Otherwise this will query the DOM on every round of the loop for every `<a>` element (which hopefully won't change as this might introduce further problems).

Comment: It didn't work, maybe I didn't write it correctly, my JS/Jquery is not very good yet. BTW thanks.